# Sorting Date Field in presence of another date field in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a tabular report in tableau, in which im trying to sort the new ship date in descending order.However the new ship dates are being sorted based on orignal ship date. So if I have more than 1 orignal ship date then all the corresponding new dates are sorted for that orignal ship date set only. 
I know this looks like a minor issue but im not able to figure out how I can make sure that new ship date is sorted independently.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Sample Output :

[image]

Comment: your sorting is as per your choice.. what is the problem here?

Comment: right now, your workbook is sorting first for Original Ship Date (ascending) and THEN for New Ship Date.

unless there's something else you didn't write, could you please share a sample output you desired

Comment: Hi Fabio I have attached sample output in the question itself

Comment: if the answer meets your needs, could you please accept it in order to close the thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to create a combined field starting from the 2 dates (select both right click and then click create combined field)

Drag it as first value in the row shelf (you can also do not show that header).

Then Sort that value according to New Ship Date like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fabio. I think combined field wont be necessary. If we only take the new ship date to the left and then sort by that date and hide it later, it would still work fine